# How to mute SoundPool by code?

Tags: android, soundpool, mute

I'm trying to search the net for muting the Soundpool that I've declared in my program.. any android code for this? As an example, I've used an If-else statement to determine the situation, whether the soundpool should be muted or not... how can I do this?

Comment: Do you really need to mute Soundpool? You can read here about the play method. Here describes the volume parameters. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play(int, float, float, int, int, float)) Or you can just pause or stop your SoundPool?

Answer (score 4):

I do something similar in the activity when `onPause()` and `onResume()` is called.
To pause all the streams which are currently played and then resume playing them you can call `autoPause()` and `autoRestore()` respectively.

Comment: autoRestore() does not exist. I believe it is autoResume() ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) , you can mute a particular streamID using the [setVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setVolume%28int,%20float,%20float%29) method at a SoundPool object like so:

```
if (someBoolean)//insert your check here
    soundpool.setVolume(streamID, 0f, 0f); //0f sets volume to zero
```

(soundpool is a SoundPool object and streamID is the return value of the .play method)

Answer (score 0):

Mute would mean to have no sound heard, yet it still plays on. You could try muting the sound stream?